# Autonomous system of ODEs: Using Picard-Lindelöf after transforming to multiple non-autonomous ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Assume I have an N-dimensional system of first-order autonomous ODEs

$y'(t)=F(y(t))$

with $F:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$ given as

$F(y)=\begin{pmatrix}f_1(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N)\\f_2(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N)\\ \vdots\\ f_N(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N)\end{pmatrix}.$

I want to prove that the system has a unique solution given some initial condition $Y_0$.

One method is, of course, to employ the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf by showing that $F$ is Lipschitz continuous. Thus I would have to prove that there is some norm $||\cdot ||$ on $\mathbb{R}^N$ and some constant $L>0$ such that

$||F(x)-F(y)||\leq  L||x-y||.$

However, depending on the nature of $F$ this may get quite tricky.

Now as far as I understand Picard-Lindelöf can also be used for non-autonomous system. Thus my idea was to choose some class $\mathcal{Z}$ of functions $\mathcal{Z}\subset \{z:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N\}$ (e.g. $z\in \mathcal{Z}$ is bounded) and to define $N$ non-autonomous ODEs for each $z\in\mathcal{Z}$ as

$y_{i,z}'(t)=\bar{f}_{i,z}(t,y_{i,z}(t))$ with 
$\bar{f}_{i,z}(t,y)=f_i(z_1(t),\ldots,z_{i-1}(t),y,z_{i+1}(t),\ldots,z_N(t))$

and then show that all of the resulting ODEs have a unique solution 
$y_z(t)=(y_{1,z}(t),\ldots,y_{N,z}(t))^T$ for all functions in $\mathcal{Z}$ (e.g. by using Picard-Lindelöf). Then I show that $y_z\in\mathcal{Z}$ for all $z\in\mathcal{Z}$, and therefore the original autonomous system must have a unique solution.

My intuition tells me that this proof is flawed. I am first assuming that a solution $y$ to the original solutions must be in $\mathcal{Z}$ and then use the results to prove the assumption (circular reasoning). However, I am not sure what part of the proof is invalidated by this. It seems like existence should still hold, however, uniqueness is not given, as I may have alternative solutions not in $\mathcal{Z}$.

On the other hand, if only uniqueness is invalidated, then wouldn't that mean that, if I could prove that $y\in\mathcal{Z}$ for any solution $y$ to the original system some other way (e.g. by showing that there is a boundary where $y'$ always points inward), then I would get existence and uniqueness? Or is that still circular reasoning in the sense: "IF a solution exists THEN it must be bounded" and "IF i have some bounded $z$ THEN a solution must exist".

**EDIT**:

Since it was pointed out in the comments, that continously differentiable $f_k$ are sufficient to prove the existence of local solutions, I should clarify two aspects of this:

1. The $f_k$ I am looking at are not continously differentiable in all arguments. $f_i$ is continously differentiable in the $i$-th argument, but not in the others. In fact the concrete $f_k$ have the structure $f_k(y_1,\ldots,y_N)=g_k(y_1,\ldots,y_N)-y_k|\sum_{i=1,i\neq k}^N w_{k,i} y_k|$ where $g_k$ are linear functions. Since the $g_k$ are linear, I can easily prove Picard-Lindelöf for those, but I fail at the other parts. However, with the approach above I can give an upper bound on the sums, and then the remaining part just also becomes linear.
2. I also require the existence and uniqueness of global solutions. That is, if I have any other argument to conclude from the existence and uniqueness of local solutions to the existence and uniqueness of global solutions, this would be fine as well. I am thinking of something along the lines of: For any $Y_0$ in a bounded set $\mathcal{Y}$ there exists a local solution on the interval $[0,\epsilon]$. However, because of the repelling boundary the end point of the solution is still in $\mathcal{Y}$ so that I can combine all local solutions into a global one. However, I am not sure this argument works.

Comment: If your $f_k$ are continuously differentiable, then your system is locally Lipschitz which is sufficient to get local solutions. No extra construction necessary.

Comment: @LutzL Yes, thank you for pointing this out. I should have been more clear on this. I am not sure this line of reasoning is sufficient in my case. First, the $f_k$ I have are not differentiable in all variables. I can prove that $f_i$ is differentiable in $y_i$, but also that they are not for some other $y_k$ (there is an $|\cdot|$ in the $f_i$). Also, I want to prove the existence and uniqueness of global solution, as I am interested in their behavior when $t\rightarrow \infty$ and I can't see how to do that with only local solutions.

Comment: Absolute values should in general not be a problem, as the derivatives in a suitable generalization should still be locally bounded. Proving a global solution is hard, positive feed-back is too easy to get into an equation. Is there a way to establish sub-linearity?

Comment: @LutzL See my comment above. The functions are in fact very simple (comming from a recurrent neural network). Each $f_k$ has the structure $f_k(y_1,\ldots,y_N)=g_k(y_1,\ldots,y_N)+y_k|\sum_{i=1,i\neq k}^N w_{k,i}y_i|$ where the $g_k$ are linear. Even more, the $w_{k,i}$ are the entries of a hollow symmetric (!!) matrix $W$ and the $g_k$ can be written as $(W+d\cdot I)\cdot Y$ for some $0<d<1$. So the system is almost linear, but the slight non-linearity is giving my suprisingly much trouble.

Comment: @LutzL Whoops, typo in my definitions in the edit and the other comment above. That should in fact be $g_k(y_1,\ldots,y_N)-y_k|\sum_{i=1,i\neq k} w_{k,i}y_i|$ and $g_k$ given as $(W-d\cdot I)\cdot Y$ instead of the ones with $+$ I typed first.

If I see that correctly, sub-linearity is not given, because $f_k(\gamma Y)\neq \gamma f_k(Y)$.

Comment: With this new definition it should be possible to find a large cube, or another convex set using the quadratic form of $W$, around the origin so that the vector field points always inwards. This gives boundedness and thus infinite existence of the forward trajectories.

Comment: @LutzL yes, I am aware that there is such a set (as I have written above "e.g. by showing that there is a boundary where y′ always points inward"). In fact, I can easily show that the boundary of the $[-1,1]^N$ is such a set. But I still don't see the clear connection from there to the existence and uniqueness of global solutions. So far I have 1) trajectories must be bounded. 2) $f_k$ are continously differentiable in the $k$-th argument (but not in the others). But I seem to be missing some theorems / definitions to connect the dots here.

Comment: Your $f_k(y)=a(y)-y_k|b(y)|$ are locally Lipschitz as $$f(\tilde y)-f(y)=[a(\tilde y)-a(y)]-[\tilde y_k-y_k]|b(y)|-\tilde y_k[|b(\tilde y)|-|b(y)|]$$ and $$\Bigl||b(\tilde y)|-|b(y)|\Bigr|\le |b(\tilde y)-b(y)|,$$ the other linear terms being obviously also Lipschitz.